# Not able to fetch data from primary table in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, join, eloquent

I have 3 tables i.e `category`, `sub category` and `products`. I have passed category id to sub category and then sub category id to product so that i can get the whole data as per requirements. The problem in i an able to get the data from the secondary tables that has joins statement not from the primary table.Here is my code of query. Any help from you would be appreciated

```
public function showProduct()
    {
  
        $data = DB::table('category')
        ->join('sub_category','category.id',"=",'sub_category.category_id')
        ->join('product','sub_category.id', '=', 'product.sub_category_id')
        ->get();

        return $this->success('date' ,$data);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `leftjoin`

```
 $data = DB::table('category')
    ->leftjoin('sub_category','category.id',"=",'sub_category.category_id')
    ->leftjoin('product','sub_category.id', '=', 'product.sub_category_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i am still getting the same output as before.

Comment: @HassanAli look like even you dont have any related record in sub_category.so do leftjoin for sub category.updated post

Comment: I have data in all the tables and did what you have said but data is still same. Category table has not been printed out.

Comment: left join will return data even if you dont have record in sub_category and product

Comment: That is ok sir. But i want data from category table.. subcategories and products are returning..